# Should I cut leafless stem off of plant?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, houseplants

I have a ( Indoor ) plant that has been drooping lately and its stems are long and touch the floor. I'm not sure if the stems are supposed to be stiff, or if that is just the way the plant is supposed to be.

Anyway, The plant seems to be dying since it has a lot of leafless stems. The plant has been neglected for a long time and I just decided to try and make it healthier. So, should I cut off the long leafless stems so the plant can conserve energy? And is it normal for a plant to have stems that dont grow upright? I didnt have this plant since it was bought so I'm not sure why its stems grow along the floor.

Comment: What kind of plant is it?

Comment: Like I mentioned i'm not sure. But it grows indoors

Comment: @Nick it's necessary to know the type of plant to help. Please make another question in which you ask for identification (with good pictures, take care of the focus).

Answer (score 4):

If you notice that plant isn't healthy state and not growing, then you can give them a CUT to promote their growth.

please note following while trimming a plant

- Make a sharp and clean cut.
- Cut where live part is connected with dead part (dried &  unhealthy).
- You should be able to see clean & live part after the cut has been done.

Give some organic fertilizer to your plant and make sure its soil remains moist by regular watering. If needed, loosen up the soil.

As you said it is kept indoor, check that it is getting some direct\indirect sunlight via some window.